# Will a http response take the same network path back to the client as the request, just in reverse?

Tags: c#, http, networking, httpurlconnection, network-traffic

Will a http response take the same network path back to the client as the request, just in reverse? Since it's the same connection, if it is internally.

Comment: What do you mean with "network path". The exact same hops (switches, routers, ... i.e. network nodes)?

Comment: Yes. Hops. What are the chances? Most likely or not likely?

Comment: Absolutely NO!!!  http uses TCP and there is no guarantee that two message being sent will use the same path and the same applies to the send and receive path.  Network routing is designed that if a router/server goes down the message will take a secondary path.  With TCP messages are redundant and normally will get sent up to 3 times if not ACK.  So it possible that a Server goes down while message is being sent and the message will take another route.

Comment: What jd says, but I'd say they can. But the chances are _pretty_ low. At least you really shouldn't rely on it but don't rely on the opposite neither. Just assume you can't know.

Comment: Fildor : It is more common that the return route doesn't take the same route as the send route.  Mask could be different and DHCP server can be different cause different routes to be used on send and receive (especially on multiple hops connections).

Comment: This is the wrong forum for this question, off topic.

Comment: Are you facing any problem related to this question, or asking just from curiosity?